# angularjs material design make card a square

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I have a material design card. Inside this card is an iframe. The iframe must be a square. It's width and height are set to 100%.

The width of the square is set by a `layout="column" flex="33"` in a parent tag. How can I make the height of this square equal the width?

```
<div layout="column" flex="33">
    <md-input-container>
        <label>Project Name</label>
        <input ng-model="sprites.list[sprites.list.length-1].name" md-maxlength="30" type="text">
    </md-input-container>

    <run-project></run-project>

    <sprites-list></sprites-list>
</div>

<blocks-list></blocks-list>
<editor></editor>
```